# .NET CORE API with Angular 4 - The cookie token and the request token were swapped

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, x-xsrf-token

I keep getting this message when trying to implement XSRF with Angular and .NET CORE: "Validation of the provided antiforgery token failed. The cookie token and the request token were swapped."  I have the cookie and header names configured the same in both the Angular and API.  Anyone have any ideas?

**Process**

Angular makes an initial call to this API method to retrieve cookie

```
    [HttpGet("startSession")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StartSession()
    {
        AntiforgeryTokenSet tokens = this.antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(this.HttpContext);

        this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(this.options.Value.Cookie.Name, tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });

        return this.Ok(
            new
            {
                Success = true
            });
    }
```

Angular then intercepts the next POST request and overrides default XSRF handling slightly since I need it to work for HTTPS URLs

```
    // Override default Angular XSRF handling since it won't work for         
    absolute URLs and we have to prefix with "https://"
    // Source:https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts
    @Injectable()
    export class HchbHttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
    private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    const lcUrl = req.url.toLowerCase();
    // Skip both non-mutating requests.
    // Non-mutating requests don't require a token
    // anyway as the cookie set
    // on our origin is not the same as the token expected by another origin.
    if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD' ) {
         return next.handle(req);
    }
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();

    // Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
       req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token)});
    }
    return next.handle(req);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit the same problem and I think I found the issue.
The `options.Cookie.Name` in the `AddAntiforgery` **has to be different** than the cookie you set manually using `context.Response.Cookies.Append`.

Try to change the name of one of them and it will work. Right now you override the generated cookie that is using the `options.Cookie.Name` name with the `tokens.RequestToken` value.

You can notice the difference in the Developer Tools.

- The default token generated using `options.Cookie.Name` is marked as `http only` (`HttpOnly = true`)
- The manually attached token using `context.Response.Cookies.Append` is marked as `HttpOnly = false`

The second one is read from JS/Angular (you can read it in JS because the `HttpOnly=false` and sent as a header in your ajax requests and validated against the default one that can't be read from JS)

Comment: Sorry forgot to update this, but your reply is correct.  

I now don't set the cookie name in start up and everything started working!